# Reinitialize ccMotionStreak for each new touch

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to trace the movement of the user's finger on the screen for my iPhone / cocos2d game.

So far I can do this using a ccMotionStreak declared in the interface to my GameLayer and initialized in my init method. To draw the user's touch, I put the following code in touchesMoved:

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
[streak setPosition:[self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch]];
```

This works until I lift my finger up and make a new touch motion across the screen. Instead of drawing a new streak, my game connects the end of the old streak to the beginning of my new swipe, and continues the same streak. This is not what I want.

Is there a way to reset my ccMotionStreak? If not, the obvious solution seems to be to create a new streak on each new touch (and remove the old one), but I can't get this to work. When I move the initialization code for my streak out of the init method and into touchesBegan, the streak no longer shows up at all.

I am guessing this should be basic to achieve, but I just can't figure out the syntax. I am still learning ObjC / cocos2d. Can someone help?

Here is how I initialize my streak in my init method:

```
streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:3.0 minSeg:1 image:@"streak.png" width:4 length:8 color:ccc4(128,128,128,255)];
[self addChild:streak];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you remove/release the old streak on ccTouchesEnded and ccTouchesCancelled?

```
// in ccTouchesBegan
streak = [CCMotionStreak streakWithFade:3.0 minSeg:1 image:@"streak.png" width:4 length:8 color:ccc4(128,128,128,255)];
[streak setPosition:location];
[self addChild:streak];

// in ccTouchesEnded and ccTouchesCancelled
if (streak) {
    [streak removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    streak = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I did all that, except I had implemented "touchesBegan" instead of "ccTouchesBegan". D'oh!